# How can i convert String To JSON OBJECT

Tags: android

I am getting an exception:

> `java.lang.Boolean` cannot be converted to `JSONObject`

How can I remove this exception?

```
HttpGet request = new
    HttpGet("http://xxxxxxxxxxxx/REST/MobileService.svcisApproved?DeviceID=123");
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
String changeTIDRec = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(changeTIDRec);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need this method:

```
 private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(is));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

String line = null;
try {
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
    throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
} finally {
    try {
    is.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    // Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
    throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
return sb.toString();
}
```

and it is used like:

```
InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
        response = convertStreamToString(instream);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/):

```
String test = "test string";
Gson gson = new Gson();
gson.toJson(test);
```